# v-switch strange v-model behaviour

Tags: vuetify.js

I'm dealing with an application that contains code along these lines:

```
<v-col
  v-for="(publication, pubIndex) in publications"
  :key="'selected_' + pubIndex"
  class="col-3"
>
  <v-card
    height="100%"
    class="flexCard"
  >
  <v-card-title
   class="white--text"
   :class="{'grey': !publication.isCitation, 'green': publication.isCitation}"
  >
  <!-- card content -->
  <v-switch
   v-model="publication.isCitation"
   color="green"
   label="Use as citation?"
  />

 ...
```

If, when the page is mounted, the objects in `publications` do not contain an isCitation parameter then this switch correctly binds to it; toggling the switch adds the parameter as "true" and toggling it again sets it to false. The card changes colour as it should.
But, if the page is mounted with isCitation already present the card is rendered in the correct colour for whether it's true or false, and the switch is in the correct position, but toggling the switch does not change anything.

Can anyone suggest what might be going wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer turned out to be the following:

1. Removing v-model from the v-switch and replacing with this:

```
:input-value="publication.isCitation"
@change="toggleCitation(pubIndex)"
```

2. Adding this function in methods:

```
toggleCitation(index) {
    let pub = this.publications[index];
    pub.isCitation = !pub.isCitation;
    this.$set(this.publications, index, pub);
},
```